# Edit (remove entries) from XML file with no new-line characters which match existing strings

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript

Okay, here's the setup:

Stamps.com shipping software stores each Marketplace's orders in a ".b" file, which is in structure an XML file with no newline characters--so it's one really, really long string.

But the software isn't designed to allow orders shipped non-Stamps.com--so orders that are shipped UPS or FedEx remain in the database.

And Stamps.com doesn't re-validate orders on next Import--if an order is marked Cancelled in the marketplace, it will not move to "Cancelled" status in the software, nor will it move ordered "Shipped" with a valid tracking number from a competitor with "Shipped"--so I need to go through and manually check off each order shipped UPS/FedEx, one by one.

Here's what I need:

I have the exports from UPS at end-of-day. I'd like to take the Order Number column from this file, and delete that record from the Stamps.com database file with a script.

The XML file is, as I stated, one line with no breaks, and I'm unsure if I'm allowed to re-post the record information from the file here--but suffice to say everything from a single record is contained between "..." and "...". It contains the Order ID in " [data] ".

So I have the start and end of a record with unique, identifiable strings. I have a list of order IDs that have been shipped that day. How do I make a script (Batch, VBScript, etc) that will remove all entries from the XML database that contain the string? It'd save a lot of time to just activate a code to delete extraneous information automatically.

Can this be done in VBScript? Batch?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Print xmlns="http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2009/8/Client/BatchProcessingV1">
  <Configuration>
    <MailingCutoffTime>00:00:00</MailingCutoffTime>
  </Configuration>
  <Layout>
    <Desired>
      <PaperID>1</PaperID>
    </Desired>
  </Layout>


  <Item>
    <BillingAddress>
      <City>Anywhere</City>
      <Country>United States</Country>
      <OrderedEmailAddresses>
        <Address>none@nomail.com</Address>
      </OrderedEmailAddresses>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <MultilineAddress>
        <Line>123 Any Ln</Line>
      </MultilineAddress>
      <OrderedPhoneNumbers>
        <Number>555 555 4444</Number>
      </OrderedPhoneNumbers>
      <ZIP>12345</ZIP>
      <State>KS</State>
    </BillingAddress>
    <HidePostageAmount>true</HidePostageAmount>
    <Identity> [some number] </Identity>
    <ShippingProfile>
      <Identity> [some number] </Identity>
    </ShippingProfile>
    <MailClass>first class</MailClass>
    <Mailpiece>package</Mailpiece>
    <OrderContents>
      <Item>
        <ExternalID> [some number] </ExternalID>
        <Name> [Item Title] </Name>
        <Price>9.98</Price>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Total>9.98</Total>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <ExternalID> [some number] </ExternalID>
        <Name> [Item Title]</Name>
        <Price>12.98</Price>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Total>12.98</Total>
      </Item>
    </OrderContents>
    <OrderDate>2014-03-12</OrderDate>
    <OrderID> **[This is the ORDER ID I want to look for]** </OrderID>
    <ShipMethod>ShippingMethodStandard</ShipMethod>
    <Recipient>
      <AddressFields>
        <City>Anywhere</City>
        <CleanseCode> [96-digit code that I have zero clue what it does, nor does Stamps.com tech support] </CleanseCode>
        <Company></Company>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <Department></Department>
        <OrderedEmailAddresses>
          <Address>ghost@nomail.com</Address>
        </OrderedEmailAddresses>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <MiddleName></MiddleName>
        <MultilineAddress>
          <Line>123 Any Ln</Line>
        </MultilineAddress>
        <NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
        <NameSuffix></NameSuffix>
        <OrderedPhoneNumbers>
          <Number>555 555 4444</Number>
        </OrderedPhoneNumbers>
        <ZIP>12345-6789</ZIP>
        <State>KS</State>
        <Title></Title>
      </AddressFields>
    </Recipient>
    <RecipientEmailOptions>
      <ShipmentNotification>true</ShipmentNotification>
    </RecipientEmailOptions>
    <Sender>
      <City>OurCity</City>
      <LastName>OurCompany</LastName>
      <MultilineAddress>
        <Line>123 OurAddress</Line>
      </MultilineAddress>
      <OrderedPhoneNumbers>
        <Number>800-Our-Fone</Number>
      </OrderedPhoneNumbers>
      <ZIP> [Our ZIP]</ZIP>
      <State> [Our State] </State>
    </Sender>
    <Services>
      <TrackingService>DeliveryConfirmation</TrackingService>
    </Services>
  </Item>


</Print>
```

Basically, this is a "block" of all information pertaining to one shipment. The "block" begins with `<Item><BillingaAddress>` and ends with `</TrackingService></Services></Item>`. If within that region, the field `<OrderID> ORDER ID </OrderID>` matches a string, I need to clear the whole block.

I've formatted the code above for easier reading, but in the file there are no linebreaks or whitespace between tags at all. I believe it has to remain as such for the software to read it.

Comment: There would be no harm in posting representative censored sample data - in fact, it's all but essential. The structure of each subrecord (how to identify start and end) and the content that is being targeted for Order ID in its context. eg `[data]orderdata[enddata][data]deleteme[order]x1234[endorder]restofdeletemerecord[enddata][data]orderdata[enddata]` - tell us the keystrings and delimiters. Next problem is size - batch is limited to ~8K. I'd suggest `SED` - like perhaps `GNUSED` (Google is your friend)

Comment: Okay, I added the code above, scrubbed of any actual address or order information.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: delete tempfiles
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,3) DO DEL q22259592.%%z 2>nul
:: create sane file
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sed -e s/\x3E/\x3E\n/g -e s/\x3C/\n\x3C/g q22259592.txt') do echo(%%a
)>q22259592.1
:: find target line numbers
CALL :zapvars
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "$" q22259592.1') DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF "%%b"=="<Item>" SET /a item=%%a
 IF "%%b"=="<BillingAddress>" CALL :billing %%a

 IF DEFINED oidb CALL :ordnum %%a

 IF "%%b"=="</OrderID>" CALL :oide %%a

 IF DEFINED se IF "%%b"=="</Item>" CALL :endb %%a
 SET "se="
 IF DEFINED tse IF "%%b"=="</Services>" SET /a se=%%a
 SET "tse="
 IF "%%b"=="</TrackingService>" SET /a tse=%%a
 IF "%%b"=="<OrderID>" SET oidb=%%a
)

sed -f q22259592.2 q22259592.1|sed -e :a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g >q22259592.3 
GOTO :EOF

:endb
IF DEFINED target >>q22259592.2 ECHO %itemb%,%1D
:zapvars
FOR %%z IN (itemb tse se target) DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :eof


:: BillingAddress line
:billing
SET /a result=%item%+1
:: If sequential Item and BillingAddress lines, new block
IF %result%==%1 CALL :zapvars&SET /a itemb=%item%
GOTO :eof

:: OrderID
:ordnum
SET "oidb="
FINDSTR /b /e /l /c:"%line%" q22259592.zap >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET /a target=0) ELSE (SET /a target=1+%1)
GOTO :eof

:: /OrderID
:oide
:: Leave Target set only if /OrderID follows immediately
IF NOT "%target%"=="%1" SET "target="
GOTO :eof
```

I use GNUSED and a file named `q22259592.txt` for my testing.

First thing is to insert a newline after each <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> then remove all empty lines from the result and deposit in filename.1

Next step is to read that result file, numbering each line and recording the line numbers for significant lines - the start of a block (`itemb`) and whether the target line contains one of the strings in `q22259592.zap` - the file of items-to-delete.

On reaching the `</Item>` line, a `SED` command is generated if the target was found which will delete the lines from `itemb` to the current (`</Item>`) line.

Whean each line has been processed, `SED` uses the `.2` file to delete the appropriate lines from the `.1` file, then removes all of the newlines and produces the `.3` file

...which should contain the data required.

Naturally, the names of the files are not critical.

**The file `q22259592.zap` is a simple text file containing the list of the OrderIDs to be deleted, one to a line.**

Comment: Thank you! I read that `q22259592.txt` is the name of the database file I'm modifying. But where are the OrderIDs to check against? They are stored in a different file (the list of which is exported at end of day by other shipping programs -- 50-200 shipments/day). Would I have to write another file to convert that export to only be a list of OrderIDs, or could I use GNUSED to read the first "word" in each line of that file as a variable to check against? Also, what's the reason for a new line at the end of every `>`, instead of after `</TrackingService></Services></Item>' and '</Layout>`?

Comment: Omitted that part - documentation amended.